# How to simplify sum of nested sums of changing number of inner sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am dealing with a sum that when evaluated at different $n$ gives:
$$x_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{1}{X_i}$$
$$x_2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{2}{X_i} - \sum_{j = 1}^{2-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{2}{X_i}$$
$$x_3 = \sum_{i = 1}^{3}{X_i} - \sum_{j = 1}^{3-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{3}{X_i} + \sum_{k=1}^{3-2}X_k\sum_{j = k+1}^{3-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{3}{X_i}$$
$$x_4 = \sum_{i = 1}^{4}{X_i} - \sum_{j = 1}^{4-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{4}{X_i} + \sum_{k=1}^{4-2}X_k\sum_{j = k+1}^{4-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{4}{X_i} - \sum_{\star = 1}^{4-3}X_{\star}\sum_{k=\star + 1}^{4-2}X_k\sum_{j = k+1}^{4-1}{X_j}\sum_{i = j+1}^{4}{X_i}$$
As you can see with this notation, we quickly run out of space. But the sequence is very symmetric, which makes me believe that there must be a shorthand notation for it. So is there a shorthand notation for this sum for arbitrary $x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following notation
$$\Large x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \left( \sum_{1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n} X_{i_1} \cdots X_{i_k} \right)$$

This agrees with your definition of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.

Moreover, you can see that this is also equal to the following
$$\Large x_n=1- \left( \prod_{k=1}^n (1-X_k) \right)$$